# ValueError: Invalid RGBA argument: What is the reason of this error?

Tags: python, matplotlib, deep-learning

I am trying to create a 2D colored bar chart

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pickle
from graphviz import Digraph
from torch.autograd import Variable
import argparse


def make_dot(var):
    '''
    Visualization of the computation graph
    Taken from : https://github.com/szagoruyko/functional-zoo/blob/master/visualize.py
    '''
    node_attr = dict(style='filled',
                     shape='box',
                     align='left',
                     fontsize='12',
                     ranksep='0.1',
                     height='0.2')
    dot = Digraph(node_attr=node_attr, graph_attr=dict(size="12,12"))
    seen = set()

    def add_nodes(var):
        if var not in seen:
            if isinstance(var, Variable):
                value = '('+(', ').join(['%d' % v for v in var.size()])+')'
                dot.node(str(id(var)), str(value), fillcolor='lightblue')
            else:
                dot.node(str(id(var)), str(type(var).__name__))
            seen.add(var)
            if hasattr(var, 'previous_functions'):
                for u in var.previous_functions:
                    dot.edge(str(id(u[0])), str(id(var)))
                    add_nodes(u[0])
    add_nodes(var.creator)
    return dot


def plot_trajectories(true_trajs, pred_trajs, nodesPresent, obs_length, name, plot_directory, withBackground=False):
    '''
    Parameters
    ==========

    true_trajs : Numpy matrix of shape seq_length x numNodes x 2
    Contains the true trajectories of the nodes

    pred_trajs : Numpy matrix of shape seq_length x numNodes x 2
    Contains the predicted trajectories of the nodes

    nodesPresent : A list of lists, of size seq_length
    Each list contains the nodeIDs present at that time-step

    obs_length : Length of observed trajectory

    name : Name of the plot

    withBackground : Include background or not
    '''

    traj_length, numNodes, _ = true_trajs.shape
    # Initialize figure
    plt.figure()

    # Load the background
    # im = plt.imread('plot/background.png')
    # if withBackground:
    #    implot = plt.imshow(im)

    # width_true = im.shape[0]
    # height_true = im.shape[1]

    # if withBackground:
    #    width = width_true
    #    height = height_true
    # else:
    width = 1
    height = 1

    traj_data = {}
    for tstep in range(traj_length):
        pred_pos = pred_trajs[tstep, :]
        true_pos = true_trajs[tstep, :]

        for ped in range(numNodes):
            if ped not in traj_data and tstep < obs_length:
                traj_data[ped] = [[], []]

            if ped in nodesPresent[tstep]:
                traj_data[ped][0].append(true_pos[ped, :])
                traj_data[ped][1].append(pred_pos[ped, :])

    for j in traj_data:
        c = np.random.rand(3, 1)
        true_traj_ped = traj_data[j][0]  # List of [x,y] elements
        pred_traj_ped = traj_data[j][1]

        true_x = [(p[0]+1)/2*height for p in true_traj_ped]
        true_y = [(p[1]+1)/2*width for p in true_traj_ped]
        pred_x = [(p[0]+1)/2*height for p in pred_traj_ped]
        pred_y = [(p[1]+1)/2*width for p in pred_traj_ped]

        plt.plot(true_x, true_y, color=c, linestyle='solid', marker='o')
        plt.plot(pred_x, pred_y, color=c, linestyle='dashed', marker='x')

    if not withBackground:
        plt.ylim((1, 0))
        plt.xlim((0, 1))

    # plt.show()
    if withBackground:
        plt.savefig('plot_with_background/'+name+'.png')
    else:
        plt.savefig(plot_directory+'/'+name+'.png')

    plt.gcf().clear()
    plt.close()


def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

    # Experiments

    parser.add_argument('--test_dataset', type=int, default=0,
                        help='test dataset index')

    # Parse the parameters
    args = parser.parse_args()

    # Save directory
    save_directory = 'save/'
    save_directory += str(args.test_dataset) + '/'
    plot_directory = 'plot/'

    f = open(save_directory+'/results.pkl', 'rb')
    results = pickle.load(f)

    # print "Enter 0 (or) 1 for without/with background"
    # withBackground = int(input())
    withBackground = 1

    for i in range(len(results)):
        print i
        name = 'sequence' + str(i)
        plot_trajectories(results[i][0], results[i][1], results[i][2], results[i][3], name, plot_directory, withBackground)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Now I am unable to debug the `Invalid RGBA argument` because I don't understand what is causing the error. I even tried to use random colors instead with `colors = np.random.rand(91,91,4)` and still the error persists.

I have checked Stack Overflow posts regarding Invalid RGBA argument (for example this, this, this and this) and none of them seems to answer my problem.

I want to know what could be causing this error. I am using the standard Anaconda distribution for Python on Ubuntu Mate 16.

Could it be that due to recent updates in Python, the solution as in the original Stack Overflow post becomes obsolete?

Comment: Please include the full traceback of your error. You also mentioned several relevant SO posts `this, this, this and this', but didn't include any links to those questions.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace

```
c = np.random.rand(3, 1)
```

with this:

```
c = np.random.rand(3)
```

It removes the error. `matplotlib` expects (3,) or (4,) shape for the `c` argument.